# Is there any way to create a TypeScript mapped type utility type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In my code I often find myself creating a lot of mapped type, on the form

```
type SomeType<K> = {
  [P in K]: SomeOtherType<P>;
}
```

When you have a *ton* of these, the code becomes a bit messy, so I thought about whether it would be possible to create a utility type, so that you could do something like:

```
type SomeType<K> = Mapped<SomeOtherType>;
```

Obviously this simplification doesn't work; `SomeOtherType` is generic so it needs its `< ... something ... >` passed to it, and also I don't know of any way to pass a type which is generic, so that another type applies the generic parameter to it:

```
type MappedType<K extends string, T extends Whatever<K>> = {
  [P in K]: T<P>;
};

type SomeType<K> = MappedType<K, SomeOtherType>;
```

... yeah, again, this doesn't work, of course, since `T` is not generic, hence `T<P>` is illegal.

I realize that I if I pass a type which is not generic but instead takes `P` as an index, this might work:

```
type MappedType<K extends keyof any, T extends Record<K, any>> = {
  [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

The obvious problem with this approach is that any record type passed to this utility type would itself have to be a mapped type, so I've only moved the problem. :)

Is there some smart way that I overlooked here? Or is there a feature request on TypeScript to enable creating mapped types with some special keyword or something, so that we could do

```
type SomeType<K extends string> = mapof SomeOtherType; // equivalent to `type SomeType<K extends string> = {[P in K]: SomeOtherType<P>;}
```

I appreciate that the overhead of writing `{[P in K]: ...}` is not huge, but mapped type is such a common and powerful feature of TypeScript so it would be nice to have some syntactic sugar for it.

Comment: ~~Probably you can do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwwN4Cga5ggLhgCIIQ4BTGANwQBsBXC4gGhzwCMiBGAJgGY2eGMCIBtbi14t+AXSwBfLFigBPJFQCyyDQBMAPAGkYFAB5QKYXRBgBrCqpAAzfGFUsYAZXIUA8lAALCgAnABV1KjMLKxsAJQpQYINDDwQ3AD50tEx2MQAFGABLMBhDWSJvSn8gsIj82QBuRWVQSFhaRgobdGxhQhhJdlxRGF5mlQiYADkKAHdwjWztJD19e0cXNQ1nGnomCA8tih3EJHSgA) but I don't know how useful would it be. ~~ Probably you should give a specific usage example

Comment: TypeScript lacks higher kinded types so there is currently no way to express such a transformation programmatically.  There's a longstanding open feature request for such types at [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) but it's not part of the language.  There are various workarounds and ways to sort of encode higher kinded types, but they are much more intrusive than just rewriting a mapped type yourself every time you need one.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find a dupe target); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that confirms my suspicion and I appreciate the link to the feature request. I'd gladly accept this as an answer